# updating either a static text or textctrl *read only* upon selection of an item in a choice box

Tags: python, wxpython

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get either a static label or read only textctrl to change it's price accordingly with the item selected in the choice widget. the lists for the Item_ID's and respective prices share the same indexes despite being on 2 different lists given their simultaneous creation... thing is no matter what Item I select, the price remains the same either way *Code above has the static text method... the read only textctrl turned out to be the same* any ideas on what can be done?

the code of the dialog in question

```
class AddItemOrder ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent,entryit ):
            wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Add Item", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 285,173 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )
            self.entryit = entryit
            self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
            self.ite = i.Item()
            bSizer25 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

            gSizer9 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

            self.m_staticText34 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Item ID", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText34.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText34, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.m_choice2Choices = []
            self.create_choices(self.m_choice2Choices)
            self.Item_ID = wx.Choice( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, self.m_choice2Choices, 0 )
            self.Item_ID.SetSelection( 0 )
            self.Item_ID.Bind(EVT_CHOICE,self.get_index)
            gSizer9.Add( self.Item_ID, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.m_staticText17 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Item Price", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText17.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText17, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.Order_Price = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, str(self.prices[self.Item_ID.GetSelection() ]), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.Order_Price.Wrap( -1 )
            self.Order_Price.SetLabel(str(self.prices[self.Item_ID.GetSelection() ]))
            gSizer9.Add( self.Order_Price, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )



            self.m_staticText35 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Item Qty", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText35.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer9.Add( self.m_staticText35, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.Item_Qty = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 120,-1 ), 0 )
            gSizer9.Add( self.Item_Qty, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            bSizer25.Add( gSizer9, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.m_button19 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Ok", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button19.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ok)

            bSizer25.Add( self.m_button19, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.SetSizer( bSizer25 )
            self.Layout()

            self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
```

the create choices and get index functions

```
    def create_choices(self,event):
        self.prices = []
        for entry in self.ite.entries:
            self.custom = entry.Item_ID
            self.customPr = entry.Item_Price
            self.prices.append(self.customPr)
            self.m_choice2Choices.append(self.custom)
        return self.m_choice2Choices

    def get_index(self,event):
        self.currIndex = self.Item_ID.GetSelection()
        return self.currIndex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to change the text shown by the statictext (presumably when the EVT_CHOICE handler in this case) then you just need to call the statictext's SetLabel method with the new text.  So, something like this:

```
newText = str(self.prices[self.currIndex])
self.m_staticText17.SetLabel(newText)
```